# how to clear browser cache programmatically in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

In my web application there is some problem due to browser cache.

How to clear the browser cache when loading my jsp page?

How can i include clear cache code in jsp page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this way in your JSP to `prevent from caching`,not able to clear the cache programatically:

```
 <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
%>
```

Comment: add the above code snippet in a jsp file and include that jsp in all other jsps. Or another easy way is to add this code while sending the response back in a filter so that you can makes sure that the Browser is not going to cache the data.

Comment: I tried with the following code, its is not caching the page but when I hit browser back button, browser says this document no more exist , reload the page. Why it is not reloading the page automatically ? `<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);  %>`

Comment: Do we need to use this with request.setHeader or response.setHeader in jsp page? I also required to disable caching in my web application

Comment: @Sadanand, did you find the answer to your question? If not, try asking as a separate question here.

Comment: @Barett no I haven't .

Answer (score 2):

```
 <%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
 %>
```

**work perfect in jsp and remember to check session**

```
<%

User u = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
if (u != null ) {
//show page
}else{
// redirect to login page
}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```jsp
<%
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```

This worked for me. [Reference](https://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/)

Answer (score 0):

How to disable browser caching for a specific JSP?
It is possible to keep the browser from caching a JSP page response. The following hints added to the response header seem to prevent most modern browsers from pulling pages out of cache when the same URL is "hit":

```jsp
<%
   response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
   response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
   response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
%>
```

The same effect can be achieved by using meta tags in the HTML header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
```

Answer (score -1):

The same effect can be achieved by using meta tags in the HTML header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control"      content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT">
```

The Cache-Control header was added in HTTP 1.1,                                           while the other two were also present in HTTP 1.0.

Comment: Not recommended, unless you have no other choice. (Not using JSP, or can't modify the response headers at the time your JSP is running -- perhaps due to an inflexible framework you're using.)