# JSP session variable not being re-read when page is re-loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jersey

We have a legacy application built using **jQuery** and **Jersey**.

I have added a new JSP page. A servlet sets a session variable and then opens the JSP page.
The JSP page displays the variable correctly.

```
<div id="my_div_id">
<%= session.getAttribute("my_variable") %>
</div>
```

After the page is closed and the servlet is called a second time after setting the session variable to a new value, the JSP opens and displays the value the session variable had the first time. It appears that somehow the display portion of the page is being cached - even after it is closed.

The JSP is definitely getting the new value of the variable. This is clear because in `$(document).ready()` , I added a `console.log()` call to print out the value of the session variable, and the correct value is being printed out each time.

In a function on the page which is called each time the page closes, I have tried various things:

`$(#my_div_id).remove()` - does not work - second time JSP page opens, the entire div has gone

`$(this).remove()` - does nothing

I should add that if a new browser tab is opened, the last value set in the session variable will successfully appear in the JSP.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: did you tried `$(#my_div_id).empty()` ? Also add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337844/10606400) to your jsp page

Comment: does not work - like remove(), next time in entire div has gone

Comment: Okay if you are getting correct value in `console` second option would be to set the div value in jquery only ,,something like this -> `$("#my_div_id").html("your variable");`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks very much